# Why does the Python help function applied to an instance return a page about the parent class in some cases and not it others?

Tags: python, types, help-system

I'm trying to understand how to get useful results when the help function is used to interrogate objects created in my code. I'm puzzled by different behavior for different classes.

```
Cls1 = type( 'FirstClass', (str,), {'__doc__':'My new class'})
inst1 = Cls1('Hello World')

Cls2 = type( 'SecondClass', (object,), {'__doc__':'My second new class'})
inst2 = Cls2( )
```

`help(inst1)` yields `No Python documentation found for 'Hello World'`, while `help(inst2)` yields:

```
Help on SecondClass in module __main__ object:

class SecondClass(builtins.object)
 |  My second new class
 |  
...
```

I would like to create a class based on `str` and be able to have useful messages displayed by the `help` function: is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a subclass of `str` and show the hints with `help` built-in, you can use docstrings. For instance the following subclass

```py
class NewString(str):
    """This is a brand new implementation of string type"""
    def test_method(self):
        """This is a test method in the new implementation"""
        pass
```

has the following output on `help(NewString)`

```
class NewString(builtins.str)
 |  This is a brand new implementation of string type
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      NewString
 |      builtins.str
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  test_method(self)
 |      This is a test method in the new implementation
...
```

But as for all instances of string the `help` method will not be useful.

The reason it fails is that when passing a `str` to `help` build-in it is treated as the name of a function, and as there obviously is not a function named `Hello World` it shows an error.

Running the following `help('help')` will output:

```
Help on _Helper in module _sitebuiltins object:

help = class _Helper(builtins.object)
 |  Define the builtin 'help'.
 |  
 |  This is a wrapper around pydoc.help that provides a helpful message
 |  when 'help' is typed at the Python interactive prompt.
 |  
 |  Calling help() at the Python prompt starts an interactive help session.
 |  Calling help(thing) prints help for the python object 'thing'.
...
```

which is the help on `help`.

Comment: …And `pydoc` makes [no provision](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pydoc.py#L1621) to treat `str` subclasses any differently.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes this is kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: "Use docstrings" isn't useful advice when the code in the question *already* uses docstrings. The important part of this answer is the part about the special treatment of `str` instances.

Comment: Thanks, I'd overlooked the fact that `help` treats strings differently by design. However, it appears that this applies not only to strings, but also to classes based on strings (such as NewString in Henry's answer). This begs the question "How does the help function decide whether to treat an object as a string naming a class rather than as a class?". I'll post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the convention here, but after searching through the `pydoc` code I would like to provide a more detailed answer to my own question (the `pydoc` help text is not very informative on the details). The

When passed an argument with type matching `type("")`, `help` checks to see if the argument is:

- in the list ['keywords', 'symbols', 'topics', 'modules', 'modules *', 'True', 'False', 'None'];
- a keyword (e.g. "from");
- a symbol (e.g. '%',
  '<');
- a topic (e.g. 'FUNCTIONS', 'METHODS');

This is done in the `pydoc.Helper.help` method. If a match is found, some specific help text is returned.

If none of the above conditions hold, the program flow continues and the object is passed via `pydoc.render_doc` to the `pydoc.resolve` function. Here, if the object is an instance of `str` (including instances of sub-classes, as interpreted by the built-in function `isinstance`, the `pydoc.resolve` function attempts to locate a module defined by the value of the argument, and raises an `ImportError` exception if there is none.

Hence, `help('METHODS')` provides help on python methods, while `help(Cls1('METHODS'))` returns an error (where `Cls1` is as defined in the question).

This explains the behaviour I see. To me, the use of the `isinstance` test in `pydoc.resolve`, as opposed to the `type("")` test used in `pydoc.Helper.help`, appears to be an unnecessary inconsistency. There could, of course, be many reasons for this that I'm not aware of, so I've raised a new question focussed on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458390/why-does-the-python-help-class-interpret-sub-classes-of-the-str-class-as-module).